# Remove diagonal background or foreground in SmartDraw after Visio import

Tags: background, smartdraw

How do I remove diagonal background or foreground in SmartDraw after Visio import?  This is very distracting on the eyes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The hatch pattern was in the foreground.  To remove the hatch pattern, I had to select multiple objects with borders and use this workflow to remove them.

Home > Fill > Hatch > No Hatch > click "OK"

Comment: A sentence or two of explanation would make this a better answer.